# What's the difference between "neural" and "neuronal"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

Is it that something that is *neuronal* has to do with neurons, while something that is *neural* has to do with nerves or the nervous system?  Is something that is *neuronal* necessarily *neural*? Or does it depend on the context? E.g., if we have that,

> A **neural** stem cell can go on to become a glial cell or neuron.

and

> A **neuronal** stem cell is committed to become a neuron.

Is the latter no longer a *neural* stem cell because it has lost its ability to become a glial cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the distinction you provide is correct, although I would not talk about *neuronal* stem cell.

A NSC (*neural* stem cell) can produce 3 things: another NSC, a *neuronal* progenitor or a glial progenitor.

The progenitors then develop to neurons or glia (astrocytes or oligodendrocytes).

Another example is the *neural* tube, the structure of the embryo that will develop to form the nervous system. Again here you use *neural* as a wider term.

Interestingly, in biology you talk both of [biological] *neural* and *neuronal* networks (although it seems to me that *neuronal* network is more used), but in informatics you talk about [artificial] *neural* networks.

Answer (score 2):

*Neural* is the adjective for **nerve** and *neuronal* is the adjective for **neuron**.

*Neural* means dealing with nerves or the nervous system. *Neuronal* means dealing specifically with neurons.

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, even if it's correct, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.